# Hibernate SQL Server Repeating Transaction Commit Issue

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008

We are using Hibernate 5.4.6 as an ORM that sits on top of an old SQL Server 2008 Database.

We are having a performance issue that seems to be related to a repeating open / close transaction code that is executed on the SQL Server.

Here is an example output from SQL Server trace:

```
set implicit_transactions off IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN 
set implicit_transactions on 
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
set implicit_transactions off IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN 
set implicit_transactions on 
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
set implicit_transactions off IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN 
set implicit_transactions on 
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
...
...
...
```

The above trace is repeated around 300 times and each one takes 20/30 milliseconds to execute.

We have activated Hibernate Logs and we can see only 6-7 SQL queries being sent to the SQL Server.

Here is the Spring / JPA configuration on the app side:

```
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
      hibernate.ddl-auto: none
      # This property disables hibernate JDBC init since JDBC is managed manually
      hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
      hibernate.proc.param_null_passing: true
```

Does anyone have an idea what can cause Hibernate or SQL Server to perform so many open / close empty transactions?

Comment: One thing: you are mixing two different dialects. Also im pretty sure it's the JDBC Driver and not Hibernate, who is sending the Queries.

Comment: It seems that this is the case - JDBC driver is responsible for the traffic clutter but we are still not sure why. I tried downgrading the driver to 7.2.2 as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15 but still no luck